# pipenv install error: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python, terminal, pipenv

My terminal/system is working perfectly until today, when I tried to pipenv install dotenv for our school assignment, everytime I attempt to enter the command from pipenv shell, i get this error:

```
Installing python-dotenv…
⠋ Installing...Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: /Users/markmorelos/.local/share/virtualenvs/markmorelos-McSWjmIu/bin/python: No such file or directory

Output: 
⠴ Installing python-dotenv...Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: /Users/markmorelos/.local/share/virtualenvs/markmorelos-McSWjmIu/bin/python: No such file or directory

Output: 
Failed to load paths: /bin/sh: /Users/markmorelos/.local/share/virtualenvs/markmorelos-McSWjmIu/bin/python: No such file or directory

Output: 
Error:  An error occurred while installing python-dotenv!
Error text: 
/bin/sh: /Users/markmorelos/.local/share/virtualenvs/markmorelos-McSWjmIu/bin/pip: /Users/markmorelos/.local/share/virtualenvs/markmorelos-McSWjmIu/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

✘ Installation Failed
```

I already tried reinstalling the entire Anaconda package as well as Visual Code. I've done `brew install --force pipenv`, and `brew link --overwrite pipenv` but to no avail. Also, since I uninstalled and reinstalled, I am no longer able to install anything in pipenv like `pipenv install pandas`, etc. The error is all the same.

Comment: What's going on with that virtualenv?

Comment: same here! I also raised a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64008062/pipenv-error-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

Using "system" option helped me.

```
pipenv install --system
```

According to help page under:

```
pipenv install -h
```

The option uses a system pip management.